# SharePoint 2013 Provider-Hosted App Not Installing

Tags: 2013, apps-development

I am encountering issues when I try to create a provider-hosted app for SharePoint 2013 from visual studio 2012. It launches fine from VS, but its never fully installs on SharePoint it gets stuck on "adding app to site", once you add an app through VS SharePoint cannot remove it either. It sticks on "we are removing your app" and eventually says "sorry we could not remove this app". Has any one else had this problem before, does any one know what could be causing it?

Things you might want to know:

- We are using SharePoint 2013 Server.
- We run SharePoint with single instance server in a VM with 4 GB RAM.
- We have App Management and Subscription services running and their
  Application service's installed and running.
- Visual Studio 2012 and the instance of SharePoint are not on the same machine.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Checked ULS Log and Event Log?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We have looked at the ULS logs and could not determine anything from them that might indicate why this is happening.

Comment: Configured your environment like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179901.aspx ?